# Is my hard drive dead or can i install Windows?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, grub

I was on my laptop one day untill it froze and when restarted my laptop  booted up and just said: error failure reading sector 0x100800 from 'hd0 error.  Then after saying that 5 or 4 times it went to GNU GRUB version 2.04. Do i need to put commands or is my laptop dead. Can i reinstall a os on it? The os it had was Ubuntu 20.04 lts. I also dont have a backup usb.

Comment: It's not worth the risk, it's only going to fail again, and possibly harder next time. Time to get a new drive on order.

Comment: As @spikey_richie points out.. your laptop is not dead.. but it appears that your drive is.  Replacing drives in a laptop is usually very simple to do as they are often exposed via simple screw panel.  Even when they aren't, they are typically the first thing you see when you unscrew the bottom of the case.